# CloudKit CKError extension not available in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit

I read somewhere here that `CKError` is not available in Objective-C, and I concur. For instance, this extension is available in Swift.

```
@available(OSX 10.10, iOS 8.0, watchOS 3.0, *)
extension CKError {

    /// Retrieve partial error results associated by item ID.
    public var partialErrorsByItemID: [AnyHashable : Error]? { get }

    /// The original CKRecord object that you used as the basis for
    /// making your changes.
    public var ancestorRecord: CKRecord? { get }

    /// The CKRecord object that was found on the server. Use this
    /// record as the basis for merging your changes.
    public var serverRecord: CKRecord? { get }

    /// The CKRecord object that you tried to save. This record is based
    /// on the record in the CKRecordChangedErrorAncestorRecordKey key
    /// but contains the additional changes you made.
    public var clientRecord: CKRecord? { get }

    /// The number of seconds after which you may retry a request. This
    /// key may be included in an error of type
    /// `CKErrorServiceUnavailable` or `CKErrorRequestRateLimited`.
    public var retryAfterSeconds: Double? { get }
}
```

The problem is that I need these objects in my Objective-C project.
I've somehow (I believe) managed to get the `partialErrorsByItemID` in Objective-C by making a category for `NSError` and a little comprehension of the documentation of `CKError.h`, like so:

```
CKErrorCode ckErrorCode = (CKErrorCode) _code;
if (ckErrorCode == CKErrorPartialFailure) {
    // When a CKErrorPartialFailure happens this key will be set in the error's userInfo dictionary.
    // The value of this key will be a dictionary, and the values will be errors for individual items with the keys being the item IDs that failed.

    NSDictionary *dicError = _userInfo;

    if ([dicError objectForKey:CKPartialErrorsByItemIDKey] != nil) {

        NSDictionary *dic = (NSDictionary *)[dicError objectForKey:CKPartialErrorsByItemIDKey];

        for (NSString* key in dic) {
            NSError *newError = dic[key];
            if (code == newError.code) {
                match = YES;
            }
        }

    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

But again, my problem is how to get the objects `serverRecord` and the `clientRecord`. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an Objective-C category that replicates most of the `CKError` structure of Swift. I didn't add `errorCode`, `localizedDescription` or `errorUserInfo` since `NSError` already provides those as `code`, `localizedDescription`, and `userInfo`.

CloudKitExtensions.h

```
#import <CloudKit/CloudKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

extern const double UnknownRetrySeconds;

@interface NSError (CKError)

- (NSDictionary<id, NSError *> * _Nullable)partialErrorsByItemID;
- (CKRecord * _Nullable)ancestorRecord;
- (CKRecord * _Nullable)clientRecord;
- (CKRecord * _Nullable)serverRecord;
- (double)retryAfterSeconds; // returns UnknownRetrySeconds if not available

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

CloudKitExtensions.m

```
#import "CloudKitExtensions.h"

const double UnknownRetrySeconds = -1;

@implementation NSError (CKError)

- (NSDictionary<id, NSError *> * _Nullable)partialErrorsByItemID {
    if ([self.domain isEqualToString:CKErrorDomain] && self.code == CKErrorPartialFailure) {
        return self.userInfo[CKPartialErrorsByItemIDKey];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (CKRecord * _Nullable)ancestorRecord {
    if ([self.domain isEqualToString:CKErrorDomain] && self.code == CKErrorServerRecordChanged) {
        return self.userInfo[CKRecordChangedErrorAncestorRecordKey];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (CKRecord * _Nullable)clientRecord {
    if ([self.domain isEqualToString:CKErrorDomain] && self.code == CKErrorServerRecordChanged) {
        return self.userInfo[CKRecordChangedErrorClientRecordKey];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (CKRecord * _Nullable)serverRecord {
    if ([self.domain isEqualToString:CKErrorDomain] && self.code == CKErrorServerRecordChanged) {
        return self.userInfo[CKRecordChangedErrorServerRecordKey];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (double)retryAfterSeconds {
    if ([self.domain isEqualToString:CKErrorDomain]) {
        NSNumber *delayVal = self.userInfo[CKErrorRetryAfterKey];
        return delayVal ? [delayVal doubleValue] : UnknownRetrySeconds;
    } else {
        return UnknownRetrySeconds;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: AWESOME! BTW, I was getting the records (Server and Client) like this: `CKRecord *clientRecord = (CKRecord *)_userInfo[CKRecordChangedErrorClientRecordKey];`

Comment: I'd avoid using `_userInfo`. Use the provided property to avoid possible future problems. But otherwise that would be fine. My added checks on the error domain and code are arguably unnecessary but it makes things clear and avoids the unlikely possibility of name collisions on userInfo keys.